# Executed on some columns and rolled back

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDITED:

I execute this procedure, it does unbound on 2 columns and roll back.. What is problem?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYchange_bindefault AS
DECLARE @TableName sysname,
        @ColumnName sysname,
        @sql nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE ByDefaults CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
select o.name AS TableName,c.name AS ColumnName from sys.columns c
JOIN sys.syscomments t on c.default_object_id = t.id
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id
 where text = 'create default default_modifiedBy as SUSER_SNAME()';
OPEN ByDefaults;
FETCH NEXT FROM ByDefaults INTO @TableName,@ColumnName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @sql = ' sp_unbindefault '''+@TableName+'.'+@ColumnName+ ''';'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @stmt = @sql;
    SET @sql = 'alter table '+ @TableName +' ADD CONSTRAINT modifiedby DEFAULT dbo.ModifiedBy()
 FOR '+ @ColumnName + ';'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @stmt = @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ByDefaults INTO @TableName, @ColumnName;
END
CLOSE ByDefaults;
DEALLOCATE ByDefaults;
```

Comment: So what's in `sys.syscomments`? I doubt that has any row anywhere with the text `create default default_modifiedBy as SUSER_SNAME()`, as that's not valid T-SQL, and that's not how default constraints are stored. Try using the non-deprecated `sys.default_constraints` instead.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Jeroen as you can see https://ctrlv.cz/nCUb there is that text, in sys.default_constraints u wont find bound defaults, only added with alter or create table

Comment: Wow, my bad. This *is* legal T-SQL syntax, for (*really*) old versions of SQL Server, that is. I learned something new.

Comment: As always, when executing dynamic SQL, use `PRINT` to see what's actually going to be executed (if anything), that helps tremendously. If the `SELECT` returns anything, the cursor should loop and produce statements.

Comment: Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns. This problem is solved.. Another problem is that it does only to 2 of 197 columns and its rolled back.